# How can we add required field in input field the required tag is not working in it?

Tags: html, angular, textbox, office-ui-fabric

I am trying to add the required field in input type even tried using required attribute in the input tag but the job is not fulfilled.

I have tried using required attribute in input tag but it is still not working.

```
<input name="otp" (keypress)="onOTPChange($event)"  [(ngModel)]='otp'
                class="ms-TextField-field form-control Login_inputWidth form-control Details_inputWidth"
                required  type="text" value="" id="otp" placeholder="Enter your OTP">
                </div>
```

I expected the required attribute to work but in actual result the it does not work.

Comment: you can try with adding `#otp="ngModel"` and then checked

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#template-driven-validation

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple example. Please note the style for the invalid border. The classes were set by angular.

For further information check: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#template-driven-validation

```
<style>
  .ng-dirty.ng-touched.ng-invalid {
    border: solid 1px red;
  }
</style>
<input  name="fieldotp" 
        [(ngModel)]='otp'
        class="ms-TextField-field form-control Login_inputWidth form-control Details_inputWidth"
        required
        #fieldotp="ngModel"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter your OTP">
<div *ngIf="fieldotp.invalid && (fieldotp.dirty || fieldotp.touched)"
  class="alert alert-danger">
  <div *ngIf="fieldotp.errors.required">
    OTP required.
  </div>
</div>
```